# jQuery functions don't work on the elements created 'on the fly'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created some elements on the fly by JavaScript like this:

```
tmpString += '<a class="small_text add" id="' + variable_id + '_add" href="#" > add </a>';
$('#mydiv').html(tmpString);
```

#### Problem

jQuery functions don't work on these 'on the fly' elements, **but** the same jQuery functions work on other normal elements (like "a" tags in my site menu).

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('a').click(function(){ e.preventDefault(); alert(1); });
```

Comment: use `jQuery.live();` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I really wish the jQuery documentation for `click` and `bind` made mention of `live` and when to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `live()` for elements that you add dynamically.

```
$('a').live("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert(1); });
```

Comment: Where did that `e` come from? You didn't use it anywhere else. :-)

Comment: @mblase75: \*sigh\* I copy/pasted from the OP. ;) Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` handler should be recalled everytime you create elements on-the-fly.